# Joomla 3.2 JDatabase or JTable?

Tags: database, joomla, record, insert-update

Until Joomla 2.5 it was recommended to use the JTable class for inserting, updating or deleting database records.

In the new documentation there will be referenced on the JDatabase class.

Which kind of procedure should be used, when iam interested in showing a database record in a form with the possibility to update this record?

What are the advantages oj JDatabase comparing to JTable?

Comment: It really depends what you are doing, but the good thing about using JTable in general is that it makes sure you are running all the APIs as intended (tracking assets, dates correct, nesting working, validation and filtering, hashing). I would never use JDatabase directly if a table class is available for user input because you would have to build a bit infrastructure to sanitize your inputs among other things. Thus for a form I would always use JTable assuming there is one available (there is not always).

Answer (score 0):

Try out [fabrik](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/1659) After a lot of search I found that quite usefull for working with the database/tables for joomla... oh and is free and has a ton of modules for it to fit your needs

Comment: We already tried fabric in the past with older Joomla Versions. We had a lot of troubles, concerning Joomla Upgrades. Furthermore some of our Joomla Sites were hacked, because of security issues by fabric. So this is not an option anymore.